# Issue when trying to look for any of the strings contained within a string array inside another string

Tags: string, excel, loops, contains

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace CheckList
{

public partial class AdHocChecker : Form
{
    // declaring variables
    private string _file = @"D:\test.xlsm";
    Excel.Workbook wkb;
    Excel.Worksheet sheet;

    private int _columnToCheck;
    private string _columnText;
    private int _rowToCheck;
    private int _rowToWrite;

    // array that will hold several string elements
    private string[] _stringsArray = new string[4];
    private string _str;

    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();



    public AdHocChecker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _columnToCheck = 5;
        _rowToCheck = 2; // starting from two because 1 would be the title of that column
        _rowToWrite = 3;

        _stringsArray[0] = "Chocolate";
        _stringsArray[1] = "Bananas";
        _stringsArray[2] = "Strawberries";
        _stringsArray[3] = "Peaches";           

        // setting Excel up and opening workbook
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        wkb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(_file,  0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",     
        true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        // letting program know that this workbook's current Active Sheet is the one we're going to work with
        sheet = wkb.ActiveSheet;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // looping through sheet's rows
        for (int _rowToCheck = 2; _rowToCheck < sheet.Rows.Count; _rowToCheck++)
        {
            // take the current string to check from column E (_columnToCheck)
            _columnText = sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _columnToCheck].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("RECIPE: " + _columnText);

            // we loop inside of loop (to check for any of the strings contained in the array)
            for (int i = 0; i < _stringsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                _str = _stringsArray[i];

                Console.WriteLine("STRING: " + _str);

               /* if (_columnText.IndexOf(_str) == 1)
                {
                    // POSITIVE RESULT
                    sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _rowToWrite] = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    // NEGATIVE RESULT
                    sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _rowToWrite] = "NO";
                }*/

                if (_columnText.Contains(_str))
                {
                    // POSITIVE RESULT
                    sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _rowToWrite] = "YES";
                }
                else if (!_columnText.Contains(_str))
                {
                    // NEGATIVE RESULT
                    sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _rowToWrite] = "NO";
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

This program opens an excel spreadsheet and loops through the rows of a column checking recipes. Then it loops through an array of ingredients and if any of the ingredients are found within the string that stores the recipe, it should write a positive (YES) or negative (NO) value to another cell.

I tried with both Contains and IndexOf (as you can see in the commented out section) but it always writes "NO" to every single row without taking into account whether any of the ingredients is inside the string recipe or not.

This is the output:

```
RECIPE: Coconut Lettuce Pineapple Sesame
STRING: Chocolate
STRING: Bananas
STRING: Strawberries
STRING: Peaches
RECIPE: Chocolate Sugar Dough Pineapple
STRING: Chocolate
STRING: Bananas
STRING: Strawberries
STRING: Peaches
RECIPE: Mint Bananas Milk Dough
STRING: Chocolate
STRING: Bananas
STRING: Strawberries
STRING: Peaches
```

According to that output the first row should get a negative value but the second and third recipes should get a positive value. The output makes me think that the loops are fine and that the problem is located with the usage of Contains or IndexOf but it seems OK to me. Any chance someone knows what's the issue here?

Have a good day,
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I forgot about a break; when the match is positive :)

After this modification it works fine:

```
            if (_columnText.Contains(_str))
            {
                // POSITIVE RESULT
                sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _rowToWrite] = "YES";
                break;
            }
            else if (!_columnText.Contains(_str))
            {
                // NEGATIVE RESULT
                sheet.Cells[_rowToCheck, _rowToWrite] = "NO";
            }
```